# Leaflet legend colours not showing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, leaflet

I am having trouble with Chrome

In Chrome, this example works for me

http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

When I apply this code to a custom map and open it with google chrome, the first colour gets applied and then all remaining colours are classed as colour #2. The HTML/CSS is correct, but it is not applying. It works fine on Firefox, Safari & Chrome on mobile, and it even works fine on other peoples Chrome, but the legend is not working on my chrome in development environment (running on virtual box) or production.

I have tried deleting cookies, application data and chrome is up to date and same version but the code is not being applied properly.

Anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: You might try disabling the hardware acceleration on Chrome, sometimes it creates some glitches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this worked for me. Turning hardware accelaration off brings back the colorscale in the legend.

Comment: Any idea of the underlying cause, and how this should be 'fixed'. Use case: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5841

Comment: No, I don't know what the underlying cause may be. Fact is that this behaviour of the legend colours in leaflet within Chrome has not always been there. I haven't been able to reproduce this since I don't know what is causing it.